# How to select from invalid table name in Oracle 9?

Tags: oracle

I am tasked to export users from an old project to another database, however the table name is `USER` (I was not around when that choice was made.)

In databases like MySQL, I could do

```
SELECT * FROM `user`;
```

But that escape character is illegal in Oracle.

So, how can I write the above query in Oracle?

Comment: Ah! I had tried, but it complained that the table name did not exist. I just tried with upper case, and it worked. So, table names are case sensitive then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double-quotes, not backticks, [as referenced in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-3C59E44A-5140-4BCA-B9E1-3039C8050C49).

```
SELECT * FROM "user";
```

Depending on how it was created - and how it appears in the data dictionary, which you can check with `select table_name from user_tables where lower(table_name) = 'user'` (with single quotes because here it's a string literal not an identifier!) - you may need it to be mixed-case or uppercase:

```
SELECT * FROM "USER";
```

As that documentation says, unquoted names are not case-sensitive; but quoted names are. One of several reasons to avoid them if you can.